# Gulp inject files from parent folder

Tags: gulp, directory, parent, inject

I'm wondering if is possible to inject files with `gulp` from a parent folder, let's explain:

I have a situation of siblings application, that should rely on common `angular modules`, the folder tree is:

```
parent
  app1
      src
        index.html
    gulpfile.js
  app2
      src
        index.html
    gulpfile.js
  common
    common.js
```

I have `browser-sync` server used in development, that serve a single application (eg: app1) starting from the `src` folder.
Is there any way to inject `common.js` in this dev environment without copying it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Realized that the problem was not `inject`. With `gulp-inject` you can get files from everywhere, the problem was `browser-sync` not serving files from parent folder.

This issue https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/709 helps in solving this.